# Just wondering what this line does/means to the computer

Tags: c++

```
    int value(0);
    while (!(std::cin >> value)) { //THIS LINE RIGHT HERE IS BUGGING ME(am really a noob)
        cout << "you entered a non-digit character\n";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
    }
```

this just stops people from entering letters instead of a number but i wanna know HOW it does it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treating `cin` as a Boolean value tells you whether it's in a failure state. `if ( cin )` is shorthand for `if ( cin.ok() )`. So the loop continues as long as the input stream is *not* OK, after taking some input.

Getting bad input is one way to get to a failure state. To get out of the state, call `clear()`, and to ignore the offending input, call `ignore()`. Then you can try again, as in this loop.

Comment: Doesn't `ignore` only ignore one character? Isn't there a better solution, like ignoring until a white-space or until `'\n'`?

Comment: @DyP Pass additional arguments to ignore more characters or up to a given character.

Answer (score 1):

If what `cin` received's data type isn't compatible with `value`, then basically it returns as false.

Answer (score 0):

`cin >> value` returns the `cin` object as a result. And it evaluates as `false` if the user-entered type doesn't match the specific overload (in your code, it's `int`), or cannot be implicitly converted to it.

Answer (score 0):

`cin` is an object of class [`istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) that represents the standard input stream. It corresponds to the `cstdio` stream `stdin`.

`operator >>` overload for streams returns a reference to the same stream and this can be evaluated in a boolean condition to `true` or `false` based on internal state of stream through a conversion operator. `cin` provides formatted stream extraction.

The operation

```
int value;
!(std::cin >> value)
```

will fail if numeric value is
entered and will return true if non-numeric value is entered.

```
    cin.clear(); // will reset the state of stream
    cin.ignore(); // ignore one or more characters
```